# Cardinality of the set of surjective functions on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the set of all surjective mappings of ℕ onto ℕ (lets name this set as F) should have cardinality |ℝ|.

How to strictly prove that?

From the fact that cardinality of every possible function is |ℝ|, |F| <= |ℝ|.
Saw similar question on this site, but I need strictly defined function that shows that |F|>=|ℝ|.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See my answer in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399503/is-the-set-of-surjective-functions-from-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-uncountable/399523#399523).

Comment: It seems helpfull, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $M=\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For each $A\subseteq M$ define

$$f_A:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
n/2,&\text{if }n\in\Bbb N\setminus M\\
1,&\text{if }n\in A\\
0,&\text{if }n\in M\setminus A\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Understood this beautiful solution, but my teacher wants injective function that would transfer subset of N into surjective function.

Could you help me?

Comment: @kushtibargo: Just modify this one slightly. For each $A\in\Bbb N$ let $\widehat A=\{2n+1:n\in A\}$; the map $A\mapsto\widehat A$ is a bijection from $\wp(\Bbb N)$ to $\wp(M)$. Now just use the injective function $A\mapsto f_{\widehat A}$.

Comment: So we make from N set of odd numbers and work on them? Did I understand it right?

Comment: @kushtibargo: Yes, that’s right: first convert the subset of $\Bbb N$ to a subset of the odd numbers, and then use my original trick.

Comment: Why this function will be injective? Different domains? How can we strictly prove injectivity?

Comment: @kushtibargo: If $A,B\subseteq\Bbb N$ with $A\ne B$, then $\widehat A\ne\widehat B$, and therefore $f_{\widehat A}\ne f_{\widehat B}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know this is unrelated to this question, but would you mind taking a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967404/dimension-of-infinite-dimensional-vector-space)? I'm trying to prove that $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R} = |\mathbb{R}|$ without using the continuum hypothesis or using the Baire category theorem.